# Topological sorts - Graph

Tags: sorting, graph

If a directed graph has a number of different topological sorts, and also for each sort of the graph, the numbering of, vertex  is the same, so its numbering must be either first or last.
Is it true or false?

Answer (score 0):

**FALSE**.

Consider a graph with `4` vertices(`0`-indexed) and the following `3` edges.

```
edges list:
0 2
1 2
2 3
```

Here, there are 2 different topological sorts possible namely,

```
Topological Sort 1: 0 1 2 3
Topological Sort 2: 1 0 2 3
```

but the numbering of vertex `2` is the same in both of them and also neither first or last.
You can visualize the above graph [here](https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/). Make sure to select the `0`-indexed and directed graph option.